# Getting a C# class exported as TLB and generated Delphi code with parent TOleControl and not TOleServer

Tags: c#, delphi, com, tlb

I'm generating a DLL from my C# code and then export it as TLB. This TLB is then fed into `TLIBIMP.EXE -P -O+ tlbfile.tlb` to get an delphi .pas file.
But no matter what I try I only get a class exported with `TOleServer` as base class and not `TOleControl`

this is my C# code

```
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("926961DC-BD8F-4BA5-ADFB-E30F713EA584")]
    public interface IBaseTest
    {
        void TestFoo();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("76113651-EE35-4BCD-A0A2-30F064976766")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    public class BaseTest : IBaseTest
    {
        public void TestFoo()
        {


        }
    }
```

The `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` is needed that Delphi generates a class which can actually instantiated.

This results in the following Delphi code:

```
// *********************************************************************//
// OLE-Server-Proxy-Klassendeklaration
// Server-Objekt     : TBaseTest
// Hilfe-String      : 
// Standard-Interface: _BaseTest
// Def. Intf. DISP?  : No
// Ereignis-Interface: 
// TypeFlags         : (2) CanCreate
// *********************************************************************//
  TBaseTest = class(TOleServer)
  private
    FIntf: _BaseTest;
    function GetDefaultInterface: _BaseTest;
  protected
    procedure InitServerData; override;
    function Get_ToString: WideString;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Connect; override;
    procedure ConnectTo(svrIntf: _BaseTest);
    procedure Disconnect; override;
    function Equals(obj: OleVariant): WordBool;
    function GetHashCode: Integer;
    function GetType: _Type;
    procedure TestFoo;
    property DefaultInterface: _BaseTest read GetDefaultInterface;
    property ToString: WideString read Get_ToString;
  published
  end;
```

Does anyone have a hint for me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect to get TOleControl

Comment: `TOleControl` represents an ActiveX control, which your C# code obviously is not.

Comment: I need do reimplement an old interface and this old interface exposes an TOleControl (which is an controll which can be implemented inside an TPanel for example). So is there a specific base class which I need to inherit from in C#?

Comment: An ActiveX control is much more complex than a simple COM component. If your component manages communication with devices, it should be non-visual, which means you don't need it to be an ActiveX.

Comment: No this is a visual component. And I'm looking how to mimic this old interface.

Comment: To make it more clear. The old interface exposes in this way graphical user elemnts (like graphs , panels and so on). And I'm trying to figure out how I can do the same way so that I don't have to change the current code which is using the old interface and which shall use my replacement interface. But I don't find enough information about How to export an C# (WPF-)Control into an TLBto use it in Delphi.